# How to create custom field validation decorators in NestJS with GraphQL

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I'm working on a NestJS API with apollo-server-express and I have the next InputType for appointments:

```
@InputType()
export class AppointmentInput {
    @Field(of => String)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    name: string;

    @Field(of => String)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsDateString()
    dateStart: string;

    @Field(of => String)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsDateString()
    dateEnd: string;

    @Field(of => Boolean)
    @IsBoolean()
    paid: boolean;

    @Field(of => Int)
    idDoctor: number;
    
    @Field(of => Int)
    idPatient: number;
    @Field(of => Int)
    idService: number;
}
```

Let's say I want to validate if the name has some "a" letter with a Pipe:

```
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class NamePipe implements PipeTransform<string, string>{
  transform(name: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (name.includes('a')) {
      throw new HttpException('The name has an a', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return name;
  }
}
```

But if use it like this:

```
@Field(of => String)
@IsNotEmpty()
@UsePipes(NamePipe)
name: string;
```

It throws me the next error:

> The return type of a property decorator function must be either 'void' or 'any'.
> Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
> Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor' is not assignable to type 'void'.

How can I solve this and use custom decorators to validate my fields? Also is important that my decorators can call services, because maybe in the future I want to validate for example the role id, and check if in the database exists a role with that id and if not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather create a [custom class-validator decorator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators) and use it like any class-validator decorator, assuming you've already applied [a global NestJS validation pipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#the-built-in-validationpipe)